# Why are my video and my image stacking on top of each other at the top of my page

Tags: html, css

I added an image to my website, but rather than starting a new line and being placed under my video, it is being placed on top of my video at the very top of the page and under the black gradient background of the centered text. How can I fix this so I can place the image starting a new line rather than overlapping over the video?

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color:  rgb(244,212,188) ;
    font-family: 'IntroDemo-BlackCapsInline';
}

@font-face
{
font-family: 'IntroDemo-BlackCapsInline';
src: url(IntroDemo-BlackCapsInline.otf);

}

.nav
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    font-size: 19px;  
    width: 100%;

}
/* Padding will create space 
    between the words and the edges of the box*/
.nav > li
{
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 0 25px 0 25px; /* top left bottom right*/
    /* This property will put all the elements
    in the same horizontal line*/

}
.nav > li > a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ee0000 ;

}

.nav > li > a:hover
{
  /*  color: rgb(116, 181, 255);*/
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

.ban
{

   background-color:  #f0ebe2 ;
}
#left
{
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #ee0000 ;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;

}

#right
{
    display:inline-block;
    float: right;
    color: #ee0000 ;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;

}

.bg-wrap .video-ele .content
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bg-wrap
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.video-ele
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;


}

.content
{
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

}

.content h1
{
text-align: center;
font-size: 65px;
text-transform:uppercase; 
font-weight: 300;
padding-top: 15%;
margin-bottom: 10px;
color: white;
}

.content p
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: white
}

#pic
{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en" >

<head>
    <link href= "Basic_Style.css" rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css">
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> Basic Site</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class = "ban">
                <h3 id = "left">Bubble</h3>
                <h4 id = "right">Contact Us: 111-444-7887</h4>
        </div>
<header>

        <nav>
                <ul class = "nav">
                        <li><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Inventory</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#">Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>

        </nav>
     <div class = "bg-wrap">
             <video id = "video-ele" preload = "auto" autoplay = "true" loop= "loop" muted="muted">
                 <source src = "coffe.mp4" type = "video/mp4">
                Video not supported 
             </video>   
     </div>
     <div class = "content">
                <h1>This is my intro video</h1>
                <p>I hope you like it</p>

     </div>

     <div>

<img id = "pic" src = "new_1.jpg" alt="picture">
     </div>
</header>

 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `position:absolute` basically causes the element to "hover" above or below other elements. In order to ensure other element's don't overlap, you'd need something like this:

```css
.absolute-element {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}

.normal-element {
    margin-top: 205px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

You'd need to wrap everything but the video in a tag and set it to sit below the video, or make room one element at a time. You could also use a div the exact size of the video that is absolutely positioned:

```css
.absolute-element {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0; left: 0;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
}

.div-overlapping-video {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.normal-element {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

With the last option, you may need to use negative or positive margins to ensure the div is exactly inside the video.